# Make database entries viewable by user permissions

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST Framework backend interacting with a database. In my application I would like to have a  contacts section, where each user can add their own contacts to the database, but can only see the ones that they added. As it stands right now I am able to have any authenticated user POST or GET from the database, but it is a "collective" database, and every user can see each other's contacts. However I have not been able to find exactly *how* I do this. The way I see it I have a few conceptual solutions, but none of them do I quite understand what I need to actually add to my code to get it work.

Here's a boiled down views.py for contacts:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST','DELETE' ])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def contacts_list(request):
  if (request.method == 'GET'):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    contacts_serializer = ContactSerializer(contacts, many=True)
    return Response(contacts_serializer.data)
  elif (request.method == 'POST'):
    //post stuff happens here...
  elif (request.method == 'DELETE'):
    //Delete stuff happens here...
```

Theoretical solution 1: Add a new element to every contact which is a "belongs to" identifier. When you pull up contacts, only select the ones match the belongs to identifier.

Theoretical solution 2: Create separated lists of contacts - so when you post, you are posting to your own list, and when you get, you are getting an entire list.

Theoretical solution 3: Find something built into Django or DRF that make it much easier... Which I haven't been able to do, especially since I don't really know *what* I should be searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theoretical solution 1 would be the way to do it as you can only grab the items created by a specific user if you store the user who created it in the first place. Once you've done this you need to update your view as follows

```
@api_view(['GET','POST','DELETE' ])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def contacts_list(request):
  if (request.method == 'GET'):
    contacts = Contact.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
    contacts_serializer = ContactSerializer(contacts, many=True)
    return Response(contacts_serializer.data)
  elif (request.method == 'POST'):
    //post stuff happens here...
  elif (request.method == 'DELETE'):
    //Delete stuff happens here...
```